# How to copy contents of one script file and replace the contents of another script file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

How can I open a apps script script file, copy its contents and then replace the contents of another apps script script file in the same account with the copied contents?

What I have so far:

```
// open file to copy from
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIdToCopyFrom);

// copy file contents?
var copiedContents = file.getAs('text/plain'); // generates error: Converting from application/vnd.google-apps.script to application/pdf is not supported.  

// replace file contents with copied content
DriveApp.getFileById(fileIdToCopyTo).setContent(copiedContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Importing and Exporting Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export?utm_campaign=app_series_100blog_121715&utm_source=appdev&utm_medium=blog)

You are on the right path using Google Drive, but you need to use the API as described in the documentation.

The key is getting the file data as JSON using the `exportLinks` this ifo can be pushed into another apps script file.

Also keep in mind that MIME type is `application/vnd.google-apps.script`